# Git Checkout from Repote Repo inside a VPN

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, vpn

We currently use Enterprise GitHub within a VPN and I was wondering if it was possible to connect our VSTS (checkout step) to checkout from our GitHub instance. Just like Azure can we setup a VPN connection to our network or is this not possible?

Comment: I don't know why this question has been put on hold and marked as unclear. It couldn't be any clearer than it already is. You have a GIT repo that is only accessible inside your private network, and you wish to use it as source repo in VSTS. Question is clearly mentioned: how can this be achieved, or is it even possible?! Any more clear than that?!! If someone does not understand this question, then s/he is not qualified to answer it, let alone suggest that something is wrong with the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**VSTS does not support GIT inside a private network.** It supported VSTS GIT and other major cloud and internet-based GIT providers, such as GitHub or BitBucket.

All of these are only accessible through internet, but that doesn't mean these are public repos. E.g. you could create a private repo in GitHub, which is only available to you. You still have to access it through the internet, but other people wouldn't have your credentials and will not be able to access your private repo.

**If you are using Enterprise GitHub, instead of VSTS, you have to use TFS.** Team Foundation Server is the on-premises based version of VSTS. Developer's and users and have exactly the same experience with TFS as VSTS. The difference between TFS and VSTS is that, VSTS is hosted, maintained, patched and updated by Microsoft, but you are responsible to host your own TFS. You could either install your TFS on your on-premises server, or you could even install and host it on your public cloud of choice, such as AWS or Azure.

**Addendum (courtesy of jessehouwing):** As a workaround you could create a private agent for VSTS and write a custom script to pull from that repo. (see comments below)

Comment: Untrue. You can connect to a local github enterprise by installing a local agent. The agent will perform the pulling of the sources. Though you may have limited availibility of triggers (only manual and scheduled).

Comment: You can also install a custom agent on a vm in azure and configure VPN on that system. The only thing that's not possible is to use the VSTS hosted agent to connect to a VPN shielded external git repo

Comment: You're right. That is possible, but I think configuring checkout from GIT won't be possible from the usual place in VSTS interface. You'll have to write a custom script to do that. Nevertheless, you're right, that's a good workaround that I missed.

Comment: It's even possible from the standard ui. The only thing that may be missing is the automatic population of the drop downs with repo names and branches. If you enter these manually, it still should work.

Comment: Overall, I think it is still fair to say VSTS doesn't support GIT repo in a private network out of the box. Maintaining a private agent is something that ideally cloud users prefer to avoid. But there could be many other situations where there is no other way but to use private agents, so it is most probably needed in an enterprise anyway.